# How can I manipulate the JSON body of a POST request using Nginx and Lua?

Tags: nginx, lua, 3scale

I am doing a proof of concept to demonstrate how we might implement [3scale](http://www.3scale.net/) in our stack. In one example I want to do some POST **request** body manipulation to create an API façade that maps what might be a legacy API format to a new internal one. Eg. change something like

```
{ "foo" : "bar" , "deprecated" : true }
```

into

```
{ "FOO" : "bar" }
```

The [Lua module docs for **content_by_lua**](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#content_by_lua), which seems like the appropriate method say

> Do not use this directive and other content handler directives in the same location. For example, this directive and the [**proxy_pass**](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass) directive should not be used in the same location.

My understanding is that the content_by_lua is a content handler like proxy_pass, only one of which can be used per location.

I don't think there's any way to remove **proxy_pass** as that's the basis of how the proxying works, so is it possible capture the request in a separate location, use **content_by_lua**, then pass to the location implementing **proxy_pass** or is there a different method like [**rewrite_by_lua**](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#rewrite_by_lua) which is more appropriate?

---

If it helps anyone else, I added the following function (my first bit of Lua) which removes the `user_key` parameter which 3scale requires for authorization but is invalid for our API if forwarded on:

```
function remove_user_key()
  ngx.req.read_body()
  -- log the original body so we can compare to the new one later
  local oldbody = ngx.req.get_body_data()
  log(oldbody)
  -- grab the POST parameters as a table
  local params = ngx.req.get_post_args()

  -- build up the new JSON string
  local newbody = "{"

   for k,v in pairs(params) do
     -- add all the params we want to keep
     if k ~= "user_key" then
        log("adding"..k.." as "..v)
        newbody = newbody..'"'..k..'":"'..v..'",'
     else 
        log("not adding user_key")
     end
   end
  --remove the last trailing comma before closing this off
  newbody = string.sub(newbody, 0, #newbody-1)
  newbody = newbody.."}"

  ngx.req.set_body_data(newbody)
  log(newbody)
end

if ngx.req.get_method() == "POST" then
  remove_user_key()
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will suggest you to use `access_by_lua`
in nginx.conf

```
location / {
                #host and port to fastcgi server
                default_type text/html;
                set $URL "http://$http_host$request_uri";
                access_by_lua_file /home/lua/cache.lua;
                proxy_pass http://$target;
                -------
                ---------
```

in cache.lua file you can do something like :

```
if ngx.req.get_method() == "POST" then
    -- check if request method is POST 
    -- implement your logic 
    return
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to what Prashant already mentioned: when you download your Nginx configuration files from 3scale you will notice that there is a Lua file included. This file is already being called from `access_by_lua_file`.

That file would be in my opinion the best place to add your body manipulation code. It will be executed for every request before the `proxy_pass` to your API server is sent.

Also, [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20140414071849/http://tech.3scale.net/2013/01/09/augment-your-api-without-touching-it) is a really good in-depth blog article about how to accomplish different transformation to your requests using Lua inside Nginx:

Comment: Thanks, I did in fact add the code I posted above to the bottom of the file you mentioned when I noticed `access_by_lua_file` was already being called.

Comment: The website you link is down

Answer (score -1):

Recently I had to manipulate upstream based on JSON value in post request and I found this useful: [NGINX LUA and JSON](http://www.energy-bg.org/processing-json-with-nginx-and-lua/)

It is basic configuration but gives an idea how to do it.

Comment: Link is down. :/

Comment: Downvoting because it's ok to link to external sources, but at the same time SO answers must provide the necessary inform without them. For exactly the reason highlighted here: the external site goes down, and the answer becomes meaningless.