# Modify request body before PROXY_PASS

Tags: nginx, lua, reverse-proxy

I have nginx setup that passes all request to nodejs, however I want to modify request body in nginx before passing it to nodejs. Like if body has http://www.example.com then replace it with https://www.example.com

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8008;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host ;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr ;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for ;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https ;
}
```

Comment: So you want to modify the POST  request's body? Not a suggested thing to do as such because it would mean reading the whole body at your server level and then make modification and pass it down. And of course you will need to use lua for the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788236/how-can-i-manipulate-the-json-body-of-a-post-request-using-nginx-and-lua

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I manipulate the JSON body of a POST request using Nginx and Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788236/how-can-i-manipulate-the-json-body-of-a-post-request-using-nginx-and-lua)