# Is it possible to rewrite SOAP POST request bodies with Apache or Nginx?

Tags: apache, http, nginx, soap, lua

I'm trying to rewrite a SOAP POST request ***body*** and ***header***, so that Apache or Nginx can proxy it to an application which resides on another server.

The request is composed like this, this one in particular refers to the "UploadDocument_v4" functionality:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://server.workstepController.Process/UploadDocument_v4"
Host: 192.168.1.2
Content-Length: 245508
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
Connection: close

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:com="http://server.workstepController.Process/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <com:UploadDocument_v4>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <com:workstepId></com:workstepId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <com:customizationId></com:customizationId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <com:document>OMISSIS</com:document>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <com:fileName>contract.pdf</com:fileName>
         <com:timeToLive>100</com:timeToLive>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <com:transactionInformation><![CDATA[
         <!--Further information for this transaction.-->
                              <TransactionInformation>
                                <!--The client id.-->
                                <ClientId>myClientId</ClientId>
                                <!--The transaction id.-->
                                <TransactionId>1234567890</TransactionId>
                                <!--Specifies if the currentWorkstepInformation should be returned by the method.-->
                                <ReturnWorkstepInfo>1</ReturnWorkstepInfo>
                                <!--The product name.-->
                                <ProductName />
                                <!--The product version.-->
                                <ProductVersion />
                                <!--The product release date in format YYYY-MM-DD.-->
                                <ProductReleaseDate />
                                <!--The email of the user.-->
                                <UserId />
                                <!--The ip address of the user.-->
                                <IpAddress />
                              </TransactionInformation>
         ]]></com:transactionInformation>
      </com:UploadDocument_v4>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What I need to do, is to rewrite this request so that it invokes the same function, but with the _v2 version. So, all the references to _v4 should be replaced with _v2 both within **body AND header**.

Is this possible in any way? I used Nginx and Apache up until now but with the relative modules I haven't yet been able to figure out a way to do this, if possible.

Thanks for any insights you might be able to provide.

**UPDATE:**
As Ivan suggested in the comments, I tried to install Openresty, and by using a basic configuration, i'm able to ascertain that it is working. However, I can't seem to be able to figure out how to replace body and header. The nginx.conf file is below:

```
worker_processes 1;
error_log logs/error.log
events{
   worker_connections 1024;
}

http{
     server{
        listen 8080;
        location / {
            --default_type text/html;
                rewrite_by_lua_block{
                --This is not being substituted
                ngx.req.set_header("Content-Type", "[...]/UploadDocument_v2")
                };
            a = ngx.req.read_body();
            a = string.gsub(a,"_v4","_v2");

            return 302 http://192.168.1.3:1234;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this can be done with [openresty](https://github.com/openresty/openresty) or [ngx_http_lua_module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module). Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788236/how-can-i-manipulate-the-json-body-of-a-post-request-using-nginx-and-lua) question.

Comment: Hello Ivan, thanks for your response. Should this work also with the request headers? Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, for manipulations with request headers there is [ngx.req.get_headers](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqget_headers) and [ngx.req.set_header](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqset_header) methods.

Comment: Hello Ivan, I have tried to configure those modules, and they seem to be correctly installed. However, I can't seem to be able to perform a simple replacement of the string. Plus, the header directive doesn't overwrite anything unfortunately. I'll update the question with the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it is about two years passed since I wrote something in Lua, but I'll try :)

```
    location / {
        access_by_lua '
            ngx.req.read_body()
            local body = ngx.req.get_body_data()
            body = string.gsub(body, "_v4", "_v2")
            ngx.req.set_body_data(body)
            local header = ngx.req.get_headers()["Content-Type"]
            header = string.gsub(header, "_v4", "_v2")
            ngx.req.set_header("Content-Type", header)
        ';
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.3:1234;
    }
```

I tested this config with `curl` and PHP script which print HTTP headers and POST request body, and it works. You can't use `return 302 ...` because your HTTP headers will be regenerated for a new request, you must use `proxy_pass` directive instead. Note that if you'll specify your proxy server by domain, not an IP address, you'll have to use `proxy_set_header Host proxy-domain.com` directive and possibly a [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) directive.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks a lot for your script, it certainly points me in the right direction. When I try to run the SOAP query, the error log contains the following: "client_body_temp/00000000005 failed (13:permission denied)". 
Did this error ever occur to you in the past? I tried some Google-Fu, but to no avail as of yet. 
I guess it's a problem with permissions to such folder, but with chmod/chown, i can't seem to be able to figure out. Thanks again for any insights

Comment: No, this error never occurs to me, but it is definitely somehow permissons-related. What is the full path to `client_body_temp` directory in your error log? Does this directory exists? What permissions does it have, what are its `owner` and `group` attributes? Under which user openresty worker processes are running? (`ps aux|grep nginx`) Do you have SELinux enabled?

Comment: Hi Ivan, the full error is below: `2018/12/06 15:04:04 [crit] 1607#1607: *4 open() "/root/work/client_body_temp/0000000004" failed (13: Permission denied)`. The directory exists and was created upon testing the script. I tried changing the permissions to user: nginx.nginx, nobody.nobody, but the result appears to be the same error. The master processes run as root, but the worker processes run as "nobody" user.  SELinux was enabled, but disabling it with `setenforce 0` doesn't change the situation.

Comment: `chmod 777 client_body_temp` does not change the situation? (Keep SELinux disabled while we do not find a source of problem)

Comment: Hi Ivan, Yes `chmod 777` on the folder returns the same result.

Comment: Hm, it seems I'm out if ideas right now. What distro do you use? I can try to reproduce this error under virtualbox, but not before the weekend. Or you can try to open a new question, maybe somebody knows the answer.

Comment: I used CentOS 7 as a distribution, with Nginx openresty/1.13.6.2. I can't ask you to see it over the weekend, I've asked too much of you already! :) In fact, if you're ever in Milano, Italy I'll owe you at least a pizza :) In the meantime, I'll grant you the answer. Thanks again